# Help interpreting integration question/determining limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm really confused by this one, it tells us that the area in question is between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and the x-axis. Now, I'm not at all certain about determining integration limits. From what I understood, you determine when $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$.

If that is the case, I figured $f(x)=0$ at $ln(6)$ and $g(x)=0$ at $ln(1)$.
Now, I have no idea what to do with that information. Should the interval be between $ln(1)$ and $ln(6)$? Tips are much appreciated, would really like to understand these.

[image: question]

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The area enclosed should be

$$-\int_{0}^a f(x) dx -\int_{a}^b g(x) dx $$

with $a$ to be found such that $f(a)=g(a)$ and $b$ such that $f(b)=0$.

Comment: Thanks Gimusi! I'm wondering, they are asking for the area enclosed by g(x) and f(x). wouldn't that be the exact area you left out + the area to the left of it? (area left out references to first point at what seems like a 2?). I'm not sure why I'm really confused by this T_T.

Comment: Yes it is not much clear, I’ve just given my interpretation selecting that part of the area enclosed between f and g which also is enclosed by x axes.

Comment: That is I’ve chosen x such that $f\le \le g$ or $g\le x \le f$ and such that the area is bounded by f, g and x axes.

Comment: I've found the answer but not really sure how to make sense of it. It would be awesome if you could take a look? https://gyazo.com/dba238c540812cdecbfa0d2e4948ae09

Comment: they say "determine the limits" and they equal both functions to zero, respectively. Then they evaluate at 0 to $ln(2)$  and $ln(2)$ and $ln(6)$ which I don't get.... since if you look at the functions equaling 0 you would find that its $ln(1)$ and $ln(6)$

Comment: Ah ok now it is clear they are asking the area between 0 and b. I update!